# Convert List of KeyValuePair into IDictionary "C#"

Tags: c#, idictionary

My scenario,

how to convert `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` into  `IDictionary<string, string>`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Very, very simply with LINQ:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary =
    list.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Note that this will fail if there are any duplicate keys - I assume that's okay?

Answer (score 8):

Or you can use this extension method to simplify your code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> list)
    {
            return list.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-collections-generic-keyvaluepair((-0-1)))))) of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` that takes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` as parameter.

```cs
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>(list);
```

Note that an exception is thrown if the list contains one or more duplicated keys.

Comment: This seems the cleanest solution? Because I think that the extension method ToDictionary recreates the KeyValuePairs

Comment: I believe it's a bit faster, as there is some optimization done for when the dictionary is created from a list: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs,162

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToDictionary()` extension method of the `Enumerable` class.