# How to convert a list of dictionaries into IDictionary “C#”

Tags: c#, linq, idictionary

There is this answer of a [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022304/convert-list-of-keyvaluepair-into-idictionary-c)

I am trying to understand what to put into this LINQ segment

```
pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value
```

My exact List definition is this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, StockDetails>> myList = new List<Dictionary<string, StockDetails>>();
```

This what I attempted but it got flagged for build errors:

```
IDictionary<string, StockDetails> dictionary = myList.ToDictionary(myList => myList.Key, pair => myList.Value);
```

As said, I am just trying to understand this LINQ part in how to properly define it for a successful build:

```
myList => myList.Key, pair => myList.Value);
```

My build errors are

```
Error   7   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,xx.Models.StockDetails>' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,xx.Models.StockTickerDetails>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

    xxxx    
Error   9   'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,xx.Models.StockTickerDetails>>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,xx.Models.StockDetails>>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: So, you have a list of dictionaries and want to convert that list into a single consolidated dictionary?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I misread the question. Please include the error message (which I suspect is due to introducing `myList` when it's already in scope) and tell us what you're trying to achieve. I thought you had a list of key/value pairs, but now you appear to have a list of dictionaries...

Comment: I have added my errors as requested. Thanks for the feedback so far

Comment: You say what you tried but not what you want to do.  What do you want to do with your list of dictionaries?  Did you mean to have a list of **key value pairs** instead?  (As in the title?)

Comment: I am just trying to understand how to create IDictionary from myList. I am trying to figure how to implement with this LINQ piece. I mean how do I define this e or d values as octavio specified.Nothing mentioned so far does not work.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need some help understanding [Lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Also you could try something like this:

```
IDictionary<string, StockDetails> result = myList.SelectMany(d => d).ToDictionary(e=>e.Key,e=>e.Value);
```

The `SelectMany` will project each dictionary as a sequence and it will flatten the resulting sequences into one sequence with all the elements that you have in your dictionaries, so, the result of calling that method is a  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StockDetails>>`. Then you can call the `ToDictionary`  method like the answer that you [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022304/convert-list-of-keyvaluepair-into-idictionary-c) before with the intention to convert the resulting sequence in a `Dictionary<string,StockDetails>`.

Comment: Sorry neither answer provides how to create my IDictionary not Dictionary result.

Comment: Dictionary is IDictionary basically