# c# Appropriate data structure for storing values from csv file. Specific Case

Tags: c#, csv, data-structures

I'm writing a program that will simply read 2 different **.csv files** containing following information:

```
file 1                  file2
AA,2.34                BA,6.45
AB,1.46                BB,5.45
AC,9.69                BC,6.21
AD,3.6                 AC,7.56
```

Where first column is `string`, second is `double`.

So far I have no difficulty in reading those files and placing values to the List:

```
firstFile = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
secondFile = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
```

I'm trying to instruct my program:

- to take first value from the first column from the first row of the first file (in this case `AA`)
- and look if there might be a match in the entire first column in the second file.
- If string match is found, compare their corresponding second values (`double` in this case), and if in this case match found, add the entire row to the separate `List`.

Something similar to the below **pseudo-code**:

```
for(var i=0;i<firstFile.Count;i++)
{
    firstFile.Column[0].value[i].SearchMatchesInAnotherFile(secondFile.Column[0].values.All);
    if(MatchFound)
    {
        CompareCorrespondingDoubles();
        if(true)
        {
            AddFirstValueToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `List` I tried to use `Dictionary` but this data structure is not sorted and no way to access the key by the index.

I'm **not asking for the exact code to provide**, rather the question is:

> What would you suggest to use as an appropriate data structure for this program so that I can investigate myself further?

Comment: Dictionary should do exactly what you're after.  `myDictionary[key]` returns the value assigned to a given key.  To quickly convert your existing lists you could use this linq: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4022334/361842

Comment: can a key repeat itself in the same file? or is it unique?

Comment: No. Duplicate keys are not allowed in dictionaries

Comment: @MongZhu No the key won't duplicate in the same file in my program. That's the logic.

Comment: @Butler1233: I think MongZhu's asking about TiredOfProgramming's requirements; i.e. to see if a dictionary is appropriate for this use case.

Comment: For a sorted dictionary you can look to System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary.

Comment: You can loop through values of a dictionary, use the foreach(var items in firstFile), and then you could use the Dictionary Key Indexes, which would be you string in this case to compare, this should help, but you may request for some code, if you need a guide

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to create a list containing all rows that exist in both files? If not, please provide sample input and the output you want to achieve. If yes, you may use linq's [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx) with a custom `IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string,double>>` that can compare your entries.

Comment: @RenéVogt exactly, if string and double values match happens in the second file (basically row in first file matches row in second file), I would like to place it to the List

Comment: @MongZhu typo has been corrected :-)

Answer (score 8):

`KeyValuePair` is actually only used for `Dictionary`s. I suggest to create your own custom type:

```
public class MyRow
{
    public string StringValue {get;set;}
    public double DoubleValue {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
         MyRow r = o as MyRow;
         if (ReferenceEquals(r, null)) return false;
         return r.StringValue == this.StringValue && r.DoubleValue == this.DoubleValue;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked { return StringValue.GetHashCode ^ r.DoubleValue.GetHashCode(); }
    }
}
```

And store the files in lists of this type:

```
List<MyRow> firstFile = ...
List<MyRow> secondFile = ...
```

Then you can determine the *intersection* (all elements that occure in both lists) via LINQ's [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect) method:

```
var result = firstFile.Intersect(secondFile).ToList();
```

It's necessary to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, because otherwise `Intersect` would only make a *reference* comparison. Alternativly you could implement an own `IEqualityComparer<MyRow, MyRow>` that does the comparison and pass it to the appropriate [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect) overload, too.

---

But if you can ensure that the keys (the string values are unique), you can also use a

```
Dictionary<string, double> firstFile = ...    
Dictionary<string, double> secondFile = ...
```

And in this case use this LINQ statement:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, double>(
          firstFile.Select(x => new { First = x, Second = secondFile.FirstOrDefault(y => x.Key == y.Key) })
                   .Where(x => x.Second?.Value == x.First.Value));
```

which had a time complexity of O(m+n) while the upper solution would be O(m*n) (for m and n being the row counts of the two files).

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but didn't want to go that complex in my program. Let me try it in the code, and I'll reply later with the results. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming You can use `Tuple<string, double>` instead of `MyRow` which already has a built-in `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @Spotted right, thought about that.. however, I like specific custom types, because often you want to add further properties or methods. But in this special case, a `Tuple<string,double>` would be sufficient.

Comment: Are we talking here about firstFile = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming yes

Comment: @RenéVogt Fair enough, it's only a maintainability vs conciseness choice.

Comment: @RenéVogt regarding your second solution with Dictionaries, it is impossible to implement as operator ? cannot be applied to to operand of type KeyValuePair<string, double>

Comment: I actually implemented @Spotted suggestion on using Tuple<string, double> and it worked for me fine. But I suspect Rene Vogt solutions would also work correctly, but lots of additional code for my tiny program.